# association count within selection

Tags: php, search, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a `Candidate` doctrine entity, this entity has a many to many association to a entity `Group`

On the index page i show all candidates.

Now i made a form with a `ObjectMultiCheckbox` object for the `Group` entity.

After selecting a checkbox and submitting the form i use the doctrine `QueryBuilder` to only show the candidates that have a association with the selected entity.

This works fine but in the form i'd like to show how many candidates are associated with a certain group. 
I can do this using the `label_generator` option in `ObjectMultiSelectCheckbox` definition in the fieldset:

```
namespace MeCandidate\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class SearchFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($name = 'search');
        $this->add(
            array(
                'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
                'name' => 'function',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'searchCriteria'
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Group',
                    'object_manager' => $objectManager,
                    'target_class'   => 'MeCandidate\Entity\Group',
                    'label_generator' => function($targetEntity) {
                        return ' ' .  $targetEntity->getName() . '('. $targetEntity->getCandidates()->count() .')';
                    },
                ),
            )
        );

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {       
        return array(
            array(
                'name' => 'group',
                'required' => false,
            ),

        );
    }
}
```

This all works as expected.
So when i select Group X it shows all candidates that have a association with Group X.

But now that only a selection of all candidates is shown the number of candidates associated with a certain group is no longer accurate as this shows the total number of candidates associated with the group but i need the number of candidates associated with the group IN the current selection.

I think i can fix it by injecting the current QueryBuilder into the form when creating the form. However i can't find a good way to get the right count.

I hope what i'm trying to do is clear, if not ask me anything.

UPDATE:
I have a working solution, in my `Group` entity i have a method `getCandidateCount` it takes a ArrayCollection of the current selection of candidates and checks if a associated candidate is in the selection. I adapted the `label_generator` function in the fieldset to call `getCandidateCount`

The problem with this is that after validating the form i have to recreate the form and inject the current selection of candidates into it so i can pass it to the `getCandidateCount` method inside the `label_generator` function.

It works but not very elegant so if anybody has ideas about how to it better i would love to hear them!

Thanks,
Yoram

Comment: Not sure in understand "IN the current selection"? If you are just filtering by the group then the number of associated candidates in each group will not change?

Comment: You are right if i select group X the associated candidates to group X is still the same. But the associated candidates to group Y is no longer correct as not all candidates belong to group X and Y.